# Catch Follows Finally block in java

Tags: java, exception

**Can a Catch block Follows Finally block in exception?**

```
finally{
baz();
}catch(MyException e){}
```

Comment: There's something very final about `finally`.  It really suggests that there's nothing else after it. :)

Comment: Ten seconds with your compiler or three minutes in the language specification would answer this. -1

Comment: +1 because it really isn't that bad a question...

Comment: @pstanton: It would be a much better question if he explained his rationale behind the question. Again, I smell an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) lurking here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels true re XY, however i still found the question/answers insightful even though i know the language `reasonably` well ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No It can't . A `try` should be followed by a `catch` or `finally` . If there is a `catch` then `finally` is the last block. This order will again depend on nesting . So you can have a nested structure like below , but again `try` is followed by a `finally` or `catch` . The `catch` after the internal `finally` block belongs to the outer `try`.

```
try {
    // outer try
   try {
     // inner try
    }
    finally {
    }
 }
 catch(SomeException e) {
 }
```

You can read more about it in [JLS 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20).

Answer (score 2):

> Can a Catch block Follows Finally block in exception?

No, not if it's for the same `try`.
But you could find this out quickly by trying it with your trusty Java compiler.

Note, that having said this, you can nest try/catch blocks if need be, but again the catch block after the finally would be on a different scope level than the preceding finally.

I'm curious as to the instigation for this question. A finally() really must always be final, and always be called, else it is not a true finally. What are you trying to accomplish with this? Because I'll bet that there is a better way, that perhaps what you have is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and that the solution is to try a completely different approach. Or is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

Only for the following case it is possible

```
try{
   try{

   } finally{
   } 
   baz();
}catch(MyException e){}
```

But it is a totally different strucute. With the structure of your question it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The construct is called as try-catch-finally. Where try need to be followed by either catch or finally or both. If all the three are present, the finally block always executes when the try block exits no matter whether an exception has occured or not.

The reason why you are looking for a catch after finally is probably how to handle an exception in finally. There is no other way rather than putting another try/catch/finally block inside that :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can check that by your own. Following scenarios are possible with `try-catch-finally`

case 1

```
 try{

    }catch(Exception e){

    }finally {

    }
```

case 2

```
    try{

    }finally {

    }
```

case 3

```
    try {

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

As you can see finally should come after try or catch. similarly finally can't be before catch.